# Receive memory warning + crash while testing through Xcode, but not on device alone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

So I'm testing my app and my console logs a message about receiving a memory warning every once in a while, which is followed by an app crash. I'm testing on my iPad via Xcode.

However, when I try to replicate the error on the device alone (running the app without Xcode) I'm unable to crash the app. What's going on? The app seems to be far more crash prone when testing with Xcode.

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact error message? And what does the stack trace look like when the crash happens?

Comment: If it's a memory warning, then I would guess that running it with all of the XCode debugging stuff running eats up enough memory for it to run out.  Maybe try running it in 'Release' mode instead of 'Debug' through XCode to see if that's the case?

Answer (score 2):

There is one hint you should try: disable Zombie objects in the Diagnosis section of the Run scheme. Usually, with zombie objects enabled, these objects are still in memory even after releasing.

Answer (score 1):

I do had same problem as you have described.
Then I have checked my code and released the allocated objects timely.
And by the time I have ran the code without crashing my app.

It seems to be you definately have **memory leaks** in code like, when you are allocating any array or something like

`NSMutableArray *myarray=[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
   You must release it. Or autorelease it.
   or for sometime you can write

```
 if(myarray)
    {
       [myarray release];
       myarray=nil;
    }
   myarray=[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```